# Alternative Proof to Showing that If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x = \sup \{q \in \mathbb{Q} : q < x\}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here is a proof for the following problem that I would like to be verified, because the hint to the problem in the back of the book suggests an alternative approach which, I think, is longer than the solution I believe I have found. So, I think that I probably made a mistake.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $x = \sup \{q \in \mathbb{Q} \, : \, q < x \}$.

**Proof**

Let $S = \{q \in \mathbb{Q} \, : \, q < x \}$ and let $q \in S$. Then for every $q \in S$, we have $q < x$, for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence $S$  is bounded above. We now claim that $x = \sup S$.

Since $q < x$ for every $q \in S$, suppose that $x' < x$. We will show that there exists a rational $q' \in S$ such that $x' < q'$.

Because $x' < x$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a rational number $q'$ such that $x' < q' < x$. Because $q' < x$, it follows that $q' \in S$.

Therefore, $x = \sup S$.

Comment: One can view the proof as complete. One small possible objection, the *formal definition* of $X$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$ is not that between any two elements of $\mathbb{R}$ there is an element of $X$. So maybe one needs to prove this is a consequence of denseness. But that is not hard.

Comment: I'm not claiming any set $X$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but specifically the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Am I misunderstanding something from the following theorem: If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $x<y$, then there exists a rational number $r$ such that $x < r < y$. Did I apply it incorrectly?

Comment: Since $x'$ and $x$ are two real numbers already specified and fixed, I think I apply the denseness of the rationals with respect to the reals in claiming that a rational $q'$ exists between $x'$ and $x$.

Comment: You mention that the rationals are dense in the reals. I agree that this quickly implies that there is a rational between $x'$ and $x$. But probably the formal definition of dense is that in any deleted neighbourhood of a real number $y$ there is a rational.   It is a very small step from that to there is a rational between $x'$ and $x$, and I think it is OK to leave it out. But very early in analysis, one might want to be pedantic.